# Live USB Ubuntu fails to see the nvme SSD on Predator Triton 700 to make install

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd

I need to install Ubuntu on my Acer Predator Triton 700 for development and the live USB fails to see the NVME SSD drive to install on.
It shows only the USB drive.
The BIOS is minimal - The only SATA mention is on main BIOS tab, but you can't change to AHCI there, there's no way to switch from RAID.
What can I do?
The system has Windows 10 installed.

So, what I tried:

- booted the live USB adn tried to install Ubuntu. It did not see any drives, except the USB.
- went to bios to disable RAID and move to SATA. BIOS doesn't let me change that, it's locked.
- tried another way: removed one SSD adn leave only one for installing ubuntu, still no drives were seen in ubuntu install.
- added back the drive to continue using windows 10.

Disabling secure boot, fast boot etc don't help at all.
My RAID can not be manually disabled in bios- IRST - unless someone gives me a custom BIOS or Unbuntu somehow manages to see the raid and let me install.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1264858/remove-raid0-and-move-windows-to-ssd-acer-predator-17)  If that doesn't help, let me know your TZ and I'll walk you through it and post an answer.

Comment: it does not work. Ido not have control of BIOS for SATA/AHCI mode.
Is there a way to install ubuntu / modding the bios to support it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe the [exact steps you took](https://superuser.com/questions/1264858/remove-raid0-and-move-windows-to-ssd-acer-predator-17) and what did not work and what were the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with NVMe SSD drives. The first automatic installation option in the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer does not recognize the NVMe SSD drive, however the *Something else* option may still be able to recognize this missing drive.

Before you start installing with the Something else option I'd like to see either a screenshot or a list of the current disk partitions in order to locate the correct place on the disk to install the bootloader. The reason why this is important is that another common problem with installing Ubuntu on an NVMe SSD drive is that the first automatic installation option in the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer is unable to install the grub bootloader. If you encounter this problem you can install the grub bootloader using the
"Recommended repair" option of a Boot-Repair bootable USB. When you reboot the Ubuntu installer it will see the existing Ubuntu installation + grub as "generic Linux" and you can select the first automatic installation option in the *Installation type* screen to install Ubuntu in place of this "generic Linux".

Answer (score 0):

Try, open BIOS, swith to **Main** tab and press Ctlr+S, the new item for change **SATA Mode** could be appeared here. It works for me on Acer Predator Triton 300 and on some another Acer books.