# After boot up using usb drive, the notebook hard disk cannot be found

Tags: boot, usb

After boot up using Ubuntu usb drive, the notebook ssd hard disk cannot be found, the desktop file only shows the usb drive information. Using application Gpart, it shows the hard disk there, file system is unknown, how to mount the hard disk for read & write, thanks!
(0) using ubuntu 20.04 LTS usb boot drive, try Ubuntu
(1) notebook model: Thinkpad E15
(2) notebook OS: windows 10 pro

Comment: There is not enough information here to offer any specific answer. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you are booting (1) the brand/model of the computer (2) the currently installed OS on that computer. With this, it may be possible to offer assistance 

Comment: Sounds a bit sus' to me

Comment: Is drive set for AHCI? And if dual booting with Windows you have to install the Windows AHCI drivers before changing to AHCI in UEFI settings. Is Windows fast start up off. These settings & often many others depending on brand are in most instructions on installing Ubuntu.

Comment: If you can see the disk in Windows, you need to turn OFF Windows "Fast Boot" option. "Fast Boot" leaves the disk in a Microsoft state that Linux doesn't understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live USB Ubuntu fails t o see the nvme SSD on Predator Triton 700 to make install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151956/live-usb-ubuntu-fails-t-o-see-the-nvme-ssd-on-predator-triton-700-to-make-instal)

Comment: Is that the version 20.04LTS, “try Ubuntu” using the usb boot drive (not for installing Ubuntu)  cannot see the SSD in the Notebook computer? I think the usb boot drive may miss some ssd driver or else, or some settings.

Comment: I test the usb boot drive on my desktop computer, having the SSD hard disk, the Ubuntu simply works. It can find & display  the folders and files in the SSD! Any tricky in Thinkpad notebook?!

Comment: I checked, the SSD in E15 (win10 pro) is NTFS, and works normal. I dump the whole SSD hard disk content with partition into 1T USB drive, plug into another computer, and cannot find partition table, and prompt for formatting. This is no wonder I try ubuntu in E15 and cannot find the SSD. How E15 is masking up the partition table? Ubuntu still cannot access E15 hard disk…